# Migrating a very large site over to WordPress (from Plone) - Should I use Posts/Pages/Custom Post Types?

Tags: wordpress, migration, plone, posts

I'm migrating a very large website that is currently on an old version of Plone (approx. 2,000 pages) onto WordPress.  I am trying to figure out what makes the most sense in terms of pages / posts/ custom post types.

Originally, I imagined moving content over into different custom post types based on the data type, with main pages being Pages, News being Posts, Knowledgebase content being a CPT called "Articles", etc.

As I'm looking at the Plone site, it seems like things are organized into folders almost like my hard drive, which would actually be much more like the Parent->Child structure of WordPress Pages.  So now I'm imagining just moving everything over into a ton of Pages with Parent->Child relationships.  But something doesn't feel right about having everything be a Page.  At least the News should be Posts... I think.

Any guidance on best practices for this type of migration?

Comment: There are several ways which you can try and test before actually migrating to live site. Like you said the content is huge so you have to do trial and error i guess. you can check plone to wp plugins too. check https://wordpress.org/plugins/cms2cms-plone-to-wp-migration/

Comment: I think you can think in terms of Category -> Posts, better than Parent Page -> Child pages. So, you can export the content as posts. As a final step you can create some pages (convert post -> page) to be linked in main menu, probably.